# creating AKS cluster with managed identity and associated with an acr by az cli script error

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-aks

I am new to power-shell scripts and I tried to run below script that will create an AKS-cluster with managed identity also associated with an ACR . **But it was giving an error at "managed identity" line.**.

```
Param(
    [parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
    [string]$subscriptionName = "azure-subcription",
    [parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
    [string]$resourceGroupName = "demoRG",
    [parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
    [string]$resourceGroupLocaltion = "East US 2",
    [parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
    [string]$clusterName = "nginxCluster",
    [parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
    [int16]$workerNodeCount = 3,
    [parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
    [string]$kubernetesVersion = "1.19.3",
    [parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
    [string]$acrRegistryName = "ngAcrRegistrydemo"
)

# Set Azure subscription name
Write-Host "Setting Azure subscription to $subscriptionName"  -ForegroundColor Yellow
az account set --subscription=$subscriptionName

$aksRgExists = az group exists --name $resourceGroupName

Write-Host "$resourceGroupName exists : $aksRgExists"

if ($aksRgExists -eq $false) {

    # Create resource group name
    Write-Host "Creating resource group $resourceGroupName in region $resourceGroupLocaltion" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    az group create `
        --name=$resourceGroupName `
        --location=$resourceGroupLocaltion `
        --output=jsonc
}

$aks = az aks show `
    --name $clusterName `
    --resource-group $resourceGroupName `
    --query name | ConvertFrom-Json

$aksCLusterExists = $aks.Length -gt 0

if ($aksCLusterExists -eq $false) {
    # Create AKS cluster
    Write-Host "Creating AKS cluster $clusterName with resource group $resourceGroupName in region $resourceGroupLocaltion" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    az aks create `
        --resource-group=$resourceGroupName `
        --name=$clusterName `
        --node-count=$workerNodeCount `
        --enable-managed-identity `
        --output=jsonc `
        --kubernetes-version=$kubernetesVersion `
        --aks-custom-headers="CustomizedUbuntu=aks-ubuntu-1804,ContainerRuntime=containerd" `
        --attach-acr=$acrRegistryName 

}
# Get credentials for newly created cluster
Write-Host "Getting credentials for cluster $clusterName" -ForegroundColor Yellow
az aks get-credentials `
    --resource-group=$resourceGroupName `
    --name=$clusterName `
    --overwrite-existing

Write-Host "Successfully created cluster $clusterName with $workerNodeCount node(s)" -ForegroundColor Green

Write-Host "Creating cluster role binding for Kubernetes dashboard" -ForegroundColor Green

# kubectl create clusterrolebinding kubernetes-dashboard `
#     -n kube-system `
#     --clusterrole=cluster-admin `
#     --serviceaccount=kube-system:kubernetes-dashboard
```

Error Msg is coming like as "**az: error: unrecognized arguments: --enable-managed-identity**".

Please help or give suggestions on how to enable managed identity also associated with AKS-clusters.

Many Thanks,

Comment: Do you mean the `az aks create` command with the parameter `--enable-managed-identity` gives the error? If yes, can you share the error message?

Comment: Thanks @Charles Xu for replay.
Yes.. that line below error msg is coming as...
az: error: unrecognized arguments: --enable-managed-identity --aks-custom-headers=CustomizedUbuntu=aks-ubuntu-1804,ContainerRuntime=containerd --attach-acr=ngAcrRegistrydemo

I also run below az command for getting assigned identity for azure subscription..it is coming proper an userPrincipalName
az ad signed-in-user show --query userPrincipalName -o tsv

Answer (score 1):

First, there is no parameter `--aks-custom-headers` of the CLI command `az aks create`, and the other two-parameter `--enable-managed-identity` and `--attach-acr`. You can try it again without the character `=`, just append the value behind the parameters:

```
az aks create `
--resource-group $resourceGroupName `
--name $clusterName `
--node-count $workerNodeCount `
--enable-managed-identity `
--kubernetes-version $kubernetesVersion `
--attach-acr $acrRegistryName
```

You can take a look at the command [`az aks create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/aks?view=azure-cli-latest#az_aks_create). In addition, that's managed identity, not the service principal, so you need to use the command [`az identity list`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/identity?view=azure-cli-latest#az_identity_list) to get the identity of the AKS in the node group and you can get the node group through CLI command like below:

```
az aks show -g aksGroup -n aksCluster --query nodeResourceGroup
```

Comment: Thanks @Charles Xu reply.
I got some infos by executing "az identity list --subscription "azure-subcription" ". But how to use this managed identity info on above AKS cluster creation script.
Pls guide me.. i am new to AKS creation.

Comment: This managed identity info hv a contributor role on subscription.

Comment: @AnirbanGoswami I think you misunderstand what I said. The command will create the identity for you, you don't need to create the identity yourself. I just can find the identity created by the command if you need to.

Comment: Thank you @ Charles Xu for replay.
I checked az --version command at power-shell and it came as "azure-cli      -->   2.0.63". I  am trying to Update the Azure CLI from power-shell .Lets see, will update ..

Many Thanks,

Comment: @AnirbanGoswami I saw the parameter `--aks-custom-headers` in the CLI extension `aks-preview`. So I missed it. And you just need to try the commands without the equal sign.

Comment: Thanks @Charles Xu..
As i am new to AKS deployment , Can u pls share a web-url for help.

Answer (score 0):

I updated `Azure CLI (version 2.15.1 or later)` by using below
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-windows?tabs=azure-powershell
and executed aks creation ps-script as above and it working perfectly .
AKS-infrastructure are created .

Many Thanks..